# Phone doesnt show up in eclipse eventhough adb is working

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, run-configuration

ive got a slight problem with Eclipse. For some reason i cant find my device in the run configurations. USB Debugging is enabled on the phone and even the logcat output when the phone is attached in eclipse works, however i cant find the phone. If i select manual in the run configurations everything gets disabled in the menu like this:
[image: Run configurations]

Any ideas why? Phone is a HTC Desire HD running android 2.2.1 and i have the Froyo sdk installed.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That window allows you to choose your preferred Android **Virtual** Device.

If you chose "Manual", when launching the application from Eclipse, Eclipse should display a dialog, asking you on which device the application should run -- your real phone should be present, in that dialog.

As an example, here's how this dialog looks like for me, after I've choosen Manual in the one your posted :

[image: Android device chooser]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/so-5133814-1.png))</sub>

The 192.168.0.10:5555 phone is my HTC Desire, connected over wifi *(I would get the same result with USB -- except I would have the model's name of my phone, and not it's IP address)*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your platform target is sdk version 10. Your Desire only has 8. Does your manifest maybe include the line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
```